# Is the within estimator from plm() estimated by Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)?

Tags: r, panel-data, estimation, plm

I have a panel data set with `N = 17 Spanish regions and T = 32 years. I performed some models like this one with the plm() function and the within estimator for individual fixed effects:

```r
mcorr <- plm(corr ~ preelec + elec + postelec + 
             ideo + crec_pib + pob + pob16 + 
             pob64, data = datos, 
             index = c("ccaa", "year"), 
             model = "within", 
             effect = "individual)
```

Then I also used this function to get the robust standard errors in order to reduce the heteroskedasticity and serial correlation of the models:

```r
coeftest(mcorr, vcovHC(mcorr), 
         method = "arellano")
```

I just want to know if it is correct to state that my model, using `plm(x, model = "within", effect = "individual")`, is estimated by Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) with individual (regional) fixed effects. I checked the CRAN paper of the plm package but it doesn't specify if the within estimator uses OLS.

Comment: What package is `plm()` from? Note that you can check the source code of `plm()` and see what other functions it is using when `model = "within"`. By following the source code and documentation this way, you will typically find your answer. In RStudio, you can click F2 on your function to see the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the within (= fixed effects) estimator (as in `plm(<.>, model = "within"`) uses OLS on transformed data (demeaned data in this case). This is the usual way to estimate this type of model, have a look at your favourite econometrics textbook.

Also from the package's first vignette this becomes clear  [cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html).

> "The (quasi–)demeaning framework: The estimation methods for the basic
> models in panel data econometrics, the pooled OLS, random effects and
> fixed effects (or within) models, can all be described inside the OLS
> estimation framework. In fact, while pooled OLS simply pools data, the
> standard way of estimating fixed effects models with, say, group
> (time) effects entails transforming the data by subtracting the
> average over time (group) to every variable, which is usually termed
> time-demeaning."

NB: `coeftest(mcorr, vcovHC(mcorr), method = "arellano")` in your coding exampel seems to have an ill-placed `)`: typically, using vcovHC function of pkg plm would look like `vcovHC(mcorr, method = "arellano")`, or in `coefest` as `coeftest(mcorr, vcovHC(mcorr, method = "arellano"))`.